# spring controller not found

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I can not resolve this issue i am new to spring so it can be silly but my angular post request is not communicating with java spring controller...

my angular code ..

```
function check($scope,$http){
 $scope.go = function (){
      var go = $http({
          method:'POST',
      url:'/addentry/pp',
  data : $scope.abc
  })  ;
};
```

my add entry class...

```
package all;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
/**
*
* @author om
*/
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/addentry")
public class addentry {
@RequestMapping(value = "/addentry/pp" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String reply(@RequestParam("name") String        name,@RequestParam("pass") String pass){
    return "hello";
}     
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
  <context-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <listener>
    <listener- class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-    class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
      <session-timeout>
         30
    </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home/index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

servlet-dispatcher.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

  <!--
  Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
  for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
  define an explicit mapping for it.
  -->
  <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

but I am getting 404 error....(addentry/pp not found)

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow too so guide me if i am wrong in asking !!!

Comment: Could you please upload your code to github? Also provide more details: stacktrace etc.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong. Are you following multiple tutorials at the same time? Please choose one and follow exactly what it says. None of your configuration here makes any sense.

Comment: yes sure, here it is....https://github.com/mouse9/o.git

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis umm yes actually i didnt get any perfect tutorial so I mixed two tutorials..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you please tell me what is wrong in this code or suggest me some good tutorials..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `@RequestMapping` annotations are wrong. You've annotated both your controller and method with `@RequestMapping` (which is fine), but the `/addentry` is defined twice. Spring will respond to `/addentry/addentry/pp`.

Remove the /addentry either from your controller (class definition) or from your method.

Comment: I don't see where your controller is declared or scanned in your spring files.